# use ES6 to improve filtering logic

Tags: javascript

In my VueJS app i have computed property, which can be related to as an ES6 function, and the purpose of this function is to filter the variable `this.classes`. putting the content of the variable aside, i fee like my solution is a bit "clumsy" and i wonder if there is another ES6 feature im not familiar with which can help me improve this logic and make it a bit easier to understand?

here the current function:

```
filteredClasses() {
      let hasGrades = this.gradeFilter.length;
      let haSubjects = this.subjectFilter.length;

      if (!hasGrades && !haSubjects) return _.flatMap(this.classes); // return all if no filter

      return _.flatMap(this.classes).filter(x => {
        return (
          x.name === this.selectedClass.name ||
          (this.gradeFilter.map(el => el.value).includes(x.grade) &&
            !haSubjects) ||
          (this.subjectFilter.map(el => el.value).includes(x.subjectId) &&
            !hasGrades) ||
          (this.gradeFilter.map(el => el.value).includes(x.grade) &&
            this.subjectFilter.map(el => el.value).includes(x.subjectId))
        );
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: What structure does do all those properties have? Can you give sample data for them?

Comment: Am I right when thinking that you want to check if there is an element with property `value` which corresponds to `x.grade`?

Comment: What does `_.flatMap` do when called without a callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could improve the efficiency by avoiding the same `.map()` to execute in every iteration of `.filter()`: create a Set for it and then check membership with `.has()`:

```
filteredClasses() {
    const hasGrades = this.gradeFilter.length;
    const hasSubjects = this.subjectFilter.length;
    const gradeSet = new Set(this.gradeFilter.map(el => el.value));
    const subjectSet = new Set(this.subjectFilter.map(el => el.value));

    return _.flatMap(this.classes).filter(x => 
        x.name === this.selectedClass.name ||
        (  (!hasGrades || gradeSet.has(x.grade)) && 
           (!hasSubjects || subjectSet.has(x.subjectId))  )
    );
}
```

Comment: Could you explain the idea of Set and Map for those who still cannot get it (I've tried to read MDN about those but ended up with nothing)?

Comment: @Sergey, it is a generic concept in programming. See wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type). In short, it is a collection of values, ignoring duplicates, and contrary to an array, it allows one to know whether a value is in that collection in *constant* time.

Comment: Thanks for explanation

Answer (score 2):

Nothing that has particular to do with ES6, but you should simplify your condition from

```
(A && ¬Y) || (B && ¬X) || (A && B && X && Y)
```

to just

```
(A || ¬X) && (B || ¬Y)
```

I also would recommend to use `some` instead of `map`+`includes`. Both these changes will make your code much easier to read and also more efficient:

```
filteredClasses() {
  const {gradeFilter, subjectFilter} = this;
  return _.flatMap(this.classes).filter(x =>
    x.name === this.selectedClass.name
    || (!gradeFilter.length || gradeFilter.some(el => el.value === x.grade))
    && (!subjectFilter.length || subjectFilter.some(el => el.value === x.subjectId))
  );
}
```

Comment: This is not equivalent. A=B=0 and Y=X=1

Comment: @TobiasWalter You're right, however for the conditions in the question A implies X and B implies Y. Maybe I shouldn't have made the simplification into letters that loose the meaining...